# How to exclude file in flutter test coverage?

Tags: dart, flutter, code-coverage, flutter-test

I am trying to **exclude** few `config` files from the test coverage results in the `flutter` test results. When I run `flutter test --coverage`, the output file `icov.info` is having information about the `config` files as well, which is affecting overall coverage percentage.

Comment: What type of config file are you using ?

Comment: @Muldec, A Dart file to keep all the constants/passwords/etc and also for translation files don't need test coverage. Basically, the question is how to skip few files from the test coverage.

Comment: Don't think it is possible today. Sorry.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25077

Comment: Could you do this?

Answer (score 25):

If you are using lcov, you can do:

```
- flutter test --coverage
- lcov --remove coverage/lcov.info 'lib/mock/*' 'lib/utils/l10n/*' 'lib/utils/colors.dart' -o coverage/new_lcov.info
- genhtml coverage/new_lcov.info --output=coverage
```

Comment: Great and simple option!

Answer (score 19):

The *most* correct answer is to use the pre-defined comments that will exclude files on the generation of the lcov.info file.

```
// coverage:ignore-file
```

```
// coverage:ignore-[start/end]
```

```
// coverage:ignore-line
```

See GitHub issue for more details:
https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage/issues/162#issuecomment-702950122

Answer (score 7):

There's a handy package to do that `remove_from_coverage`

https://pub.dev/packages/remove_from_coverage

This is the usage help:

```
Remove files with paths matching given PATTERNs from the lcov.info FILE
-f, --file=<FILE>         the target lcov.info file to manipulate
-r, --remove=<PATTERN>    a pattern of paths to exclude from coverage
-h, --help                show this help
```

Basically add it to your `dev_dependencies` if you want to run this in your pipeline or install it globally.

Answer (score 1):

I use https://pub.dev/packages/remove_from_coverage

1. install `dart pub global activate remove_from_coverage`
2. Run test with coverage `flutter test --coverage`
3. Filter you lcov file. In my case i filter with use_cases folders of my project. `remove_from_coverage -f coverage/lcov.info -r '^[^\/]+\/[^\/]+(?!.*\/use_cases\/).*$'`

Additionally if you like visualization the coverage in html file you can use genhtml.  `genhtml coverage/lcov.info -o coverage/html`

Answer (score 0):

Below is solution to exclude required folder from coverage in terms of github action.

```
jobs:
  test:
    name: Unit test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: ⚙️ Install lcov
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get -y install lcov
      - name: Setup Flutter
        uses: //flutter setup action goes here.
      - name: Run flutter tests
        run: |
          flutter test --coverage 
          lcov --remove coverage/lcov.info 'lib/generated-code/*'  -o ./coverage/coverage_with_exclusion.info 
          genhtml ./coverage/coverage_with_exclusion.info -o ./coverage
      - name: Coverage Report
        uses: romeovs/lcov-reporter-action@v0.3.1
        with:
         lcov-file: ./coverage/coverage_with_exclusion.info
         title: 'Code Coverage Report'
```

We are removing the default `coverage/lcov.info` file and excluding all files within `lib/generated-code/` folder and generating a new coverage file named `coverage_with_exclusion.info`

And the same file is used in the Coverage Report step.